# querying and converting a neo4j query result to multi dimensional @QueryResult object

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a @QueryResult interface, which itself declares a getter method that returns a list of objects of the same type. I wonder if there is a way to convert a neo4j query result to a proxied object that implements this domain interface ?

Here is the interface of the domain I tried for testing, which did not work:

```
 @QueryResult
   public interface Test
   {
       @ResultColumn( "id" )
       public String getId();
       @ResultColumn( "name" )
       public String getName();
       @ResultColumn( "tests" );
       java.util.Collection<Test> getTests();
   }
```

I used neo4Template#query( String, Map) to convert the query below to a proxied object that implements the above interface

```
  MATCH (n:Label {id:{id}) WITH n MATCH (n)-[:INCLUDES]->(s) with n, s, COLLECT ({id:s.id, name:s.name}) AS tests RETURN n.name as name, n.id as id, tests
```

However, I got this exception: 
Expexted a column named toString to be in the result set.
    at

```
org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.ResultColumnValueExtractor.extractFromAccessibleObject(ResultColumnValueExtractor.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.ResultColumnValueExtractor.extractFromMethod(ResultColumnValueExtractor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.QueryResultProxy.invoke(QueryResultProxy.java:54)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.single(IteratorUtil.java:338)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.singleOrNull(IteratorUtil.java:128)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.singleOrNull(IteratorUtil.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder.singleOrNull(QueryResultBuilder.java:71)
```

Does anyone know if this is possible to achieve using spring data neo4j? Thanks for your help

Comment: I think only primitive types are supported and perhaps mapped entities, but I'm not sure about the latter. I don't think @QueryResults themselves are currently supported.

Comment: That helps. Thanks :) I am not entirely sure what you meant by "mapped entities"?. Supporting nested @QueryResult would be a nice feature. In the meantime, I see one way of getting around this is to  iterate over each Map<String, Object> row and manually convert each result row to java object. It is sort of troublesome. I am not sure if there is a better way

Comment: Mapped entity = > something that is annotated @Node